# Get the PID on the host from inside the container?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, pid, rhel8

Before Linux Kernel v4, I was able to obtain the host PID from inside the docker container from the process scheduling information.

For instance, if I run `sleep` command inside the container and my local PID is 37, then I can check the actual PID on the host via:

```
root@helloworld-595777cb8b-gjg4j:/# head /proc/37/sched
sleep (27062, #threads: 1)
```

I can verify on the host that the PID `27062` corresponds to the process within the container.

```
root      27062  0.0  0.0   4312   352 pts/0    S    16:29   0:00 sleep 3000
```

I have tried this with on RHEL7 (Kernel: Linux 3.10) with Docker version: 17.09.0-ce.

I am not able to reproduce the same result on RHEL8 (Kernel: Linux 4.18) with Docker version: 20.10. In fact, I always get the local PID from the scheduling information.

```
/ # head /proc/8/sched
sleep (8, #threads: 1)
```

I might be wrong but my assumption is that something is changed within the Kernel which forbids to obtain the host PID?

So the question is how to obtain the host PID from within the container?

Comment: You can try this `for i in $(docker container ls --format "{{.ID}}"); do docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}} {{.Name}}' $i; done`

Comment: @DreamBold OP wants to do this from *within the container*.

Comment: Can you connect to the instance running? `docker exec -it your-container-id /bin/bash` ? Then you can use regular ubuntu commands to check the process id

Comment: You should not be able to obtain the host PID from within the container. That's what a container is intended for. If you want, you can start the container with `--pid=host` to use the same PID namespace, but then you would not have different PIDs for processes inside the container.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoBonelli. I know same PID namespace is a solution but I like to avoid that.

Comment: @DreamBold Yes, I can connect to the container and execute the commands to retrieve the pid. But the pid is always the local pid from inside the container. But I want to know the actual pid on the host. This was possible before Linux 4.

Comment: `docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' <container id>` Did you try this command?

Comment: @DreamBold I need to know the host pid from __within__ the container, and not from the host.

Comment: Am not sure what you mean, running `ps -a` or `ps aux` on the console of the container doesn't work for you?

Comment: @DreamBold I think you are not understanding the concept of [PID namespaces](https://manned.org/pid_namespaces.7), which is essentially what creates OP's problem, making host PIDs and container PIDs different.

Answer (score 0):

The bug (or "feature" if you prefer) that allowed the host PID to be discovered from /proc/PID/sched in the container was fixed (or "broken" if you prefer) in Linux kernel 4.14 by [commit 74dc3384fc79](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=74dc3384fc7983b78cc46ebb1824968a3db85eb1) ("[sched/debug: Use task_pid_nr_ns in /proc/$pid/sched](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=74dc3384fc7983b78cc46ebb1824968a3db85eb1)").

As a result of the change, the container cannot get the host PID of a process (at least via /proc/PID/sched) if PID namespaces are in use.

Comment: That's very useful information. Thanks. Do you have a suggestion to find a workaround a part from running into the same PID namespace?

Comment: @Muzammil I think any workaround would be considered to be a bug by the kernel maintainers.